# php tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $fileName); saves in wierd name

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, localhost, temp

i'm using to `tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $fileName);` to temporary save an image in the /private/var/tmp.

The images  are being save with a weird text after them
For example:

> 10153114610662388_1434185314.jpggd5Wc6

After i'm saving them, I'm uploading them to facebook and it gives me the following error `{"error":"(#324) Requires upload file"}` and I think it because of that.

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) for `tempnam`:

> ```
> string tempnam ( string $dir , string $prefix )
> ```
>
> dir The directory where the temporary filename will be created.
>
> prefix The prefix of the generated temporary filename.

So the second parameter is a prefix for the filename, not the filename that it will use. `tempnam` makes sure that the filename is unique (so you don't overwrite another temp file) - and that's what the "weird text" at the end is for.

If you want to save the file with the filename you already have just use it directly - but understand that if a file with that name already exists you'll overwrite it.